# VPN between 2 sites using Software only

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, site-to-site-vpn

I have 2 servers at 2 separate locations.

Location A 192.168.1.0/24
Location B 192.168.0.0/24

I want site to site vpn between both servers and allow all clients to connect through these servers to allow full connectivity throughout the network.

I have had a look at softether and a few others.

Does anyone have any experience of such things, any help or recommendations?

Hardware is a no go at present... we are not-for-profit.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: See if this video helps. https://youtu.be/PhdYo2tqjCU The idea is to provide a vpn between the 2 servers and establish routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Routing and Remote Access role in Windows Server. You'll want to configure a site-to-site VPN utilizing your servers at each site as a router/VPN gateway.

Of course, there are many security considerations to take into account when doing this, and I wouldn't run any other roles or services on a box being used for RRAS, but that's too deep of a discussion for this format. This document library is a good start for learning: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754634(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Hey, Can I ask how stable you find RRAS. I've heard multiple stories relating too RRAS with it randomly disconnecting and not reconnecting. Is this a common thing or is it fairly stable?

Comment: A properly configured RRAS should be stable.